# Force AngularJS to reload a route although option reloadOnSearch is set to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

In the route configuration of my AngularJS application most of the routes are defined with the option `reloadOnSearch` set to `false` as most of the time a page should not reload when search parameter changed.

But in rare circumstances I need a different behaviour where I need to reload the URL although only the search parameters changed.

Is there a way to force AngularJS to reload the URL although `reloadOnSearch` is set to `false`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have not tried it, but something that you can try is.

In the `$routeUpdate` event handler call the `$route.reload()` method if you know the condition that should cause refresh of route.

Comment: What do you mean with $routeUpdate event handler, how can I configure its behaviour or is it part of the AngularJS core? I don't want to change the framework itself to be able to update the version later.

Comment: Ah ok, now I got what you meant. I should listen to the $routeUpdate event and then reload when necessary.

Comment: Basically you can do $route.reload() anytime you want. When to do is upto you. Since you want to refresh the view in a case when the search query changes, right. How would you know that search query has changed. This event is raise when search query is updated.

Comment: It would have been helpful that you included an example

Comment: `function myController($route, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.$on('$routeUpdate', function() {
        if (/*shouldReload*/) {
          $route.reload();
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: Short hint. If you have _a concrete point in the code_ where you are adding search params to the URL, but they are not provoking a reload because of having `reloadOnSearch: false` for that route, as @Chandermani said you can execute `$route.reload()` wherever you need it.

So just include the `$route` service as a dependencie of your class and execute `$route.reload()` on that concrete point you need it.

Answer (score 13):

In case you are trying to force reload when a user clicks a link, set link's target attribute. It will trigger reload regardless of reloadOnSearch=false

```
<a href="/same_page?different_param=123" target="_self">Reload</a>
```

Comment: Man! You made my day! This indeed is a hack, but it works beautifully and is sufficient for some limited needs. Thanks!

Comment: This will reload the entire application not just the route. The non-hacky way is to use 
ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}"

Answer (score 1):

This is also work

```
app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope,$window){
           $scope.reload =function(){
               $window.location.reload(); 
           }
})
```

html

```
<div ng-click="reload()">reload</div>
```

Comment: Although question was not formed in such a way to clarify whether he/she wants to reload the route or the whole application, I am pretty sure that he wants to reload the route. Your solution re-initializes the whole application.