# Is there a way to conditionally turn off reloadOnSearch in a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a controller where I *sometimes* update the location using `$location.search({param1: newParam1Value)`.

When I purposely change $location.search in the controller I would like to prevent a reload.  Otherwise, I want to keep the default `reloadOnSearch` behavior for this route/state.

I can set `reloadOnSearch` to false when I define the state but then it will always be false.

Is there a way to toggle the `reloadOnSearch` for the route from within the controller?  Alternatively, can I keep `reloadOnSearch: true` and just prevent reload some other way for the one instance where I don't want it to happen?

I am using `ui.router`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137504/force-angularjs-to-reload-a-route-although-option-reloadonsearch-is-set-to-false

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact opposite of what is described in that post

Comment: It's the same. You need to hook $routeUpdate, and delegate to $route.reload(), unless you updated the route...

Comment: @PhilPrice Yes, set reloadOnSearch to false and then listen for $routeUpdate events.
From docs: 
reloadOnSearch, If the option is set to false and url in the browser changes, then $routeUpdate event is broadcasted on the root scope.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!! you can use `reloadOnSearch` conditionally. We know that state gets reloaded with $location.search() event. If your use case is like this, that in some case you want to reload state and in other case you don't, then use `reloadOnSearch` like this:

```
$scope.myClickEvent = function () {
    // prevent a reload
    $state.current.reloadOnSearch = false;
    $location.search('page', 2);

    // Do your code...

   loadData();
}
```

/*
API call to load data
*/

```
var function loadData() {
  // Do your code...

  // Allow to reload state
  $state.current.reloadOnSearch = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed this same functionality, and here's what I came up with:

As stated elsewhere, you need to turn `reloadOnSearch = false`  in the route.  But MOST of the time, you want it to act like it used to with it set to `true`.  You just want to skip in certain circumstances.  So I added this to my controller:

```
    $rootScope.skipNextSearchChangeReload = false;
    $scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(){
        if (!$rootScope.skipNextSearchChangeReload) {
            $route.reload();
        } else {
            // skip reload, but reset to stop skipping
            $rootScope.skipNextSearchChangeReload = false;
        }
    });

    var updateSearchWithoutReload = function(key, values) {
        $rootScope.skipNextSearchChangeReload = true;
        $location.search(key, values);
    };
```

then all changes to the url will still reload as usual.  But when you want to skip the reload, you call `updateSearchWithoutReload(key, values);` and it will skip for just that call.  Then, after having skipped, it will reset to not skip reload.

I had tried just setting `$rootScope.skipNextSearchChangeReload = true` and then `$location.search(k, v)` and then `$rootScope.skipNextSearchChangeReload = false`, but apparently the events hadn't propagated all the way through and `skipNextSearchChangeReload` was set to `false` before it had skipped.  So this was the best I could come up with.