# Reload page on browser back/forward button in AngularJS with ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, html5-history

I have the following  config for ui router state in my angularjs app.

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '/index?zoom&center',
            views: {
                'map': {
                    controller: 'MapCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'map.html'
                }
            },
            reloadOnSearch:false
    });
```

However, the back forward button in the browser go to different url, but I need to reload the page with the urls as stateParams.

For example:
User1 go to page http://www.example.com/index?zoom=2&center=1,2. 
then he does bunch operation in the page, the url becomes http://www.example.com/index?zoom=12&center=3,4

Then he presses the back button, the url changes to the previous one, but I need to reload my page to let the controller read the query parameters to do the right thing...

Any way to let it work with browser back/forward?

Comment: "but the page does not refresh"- if you mean that page doesn't get full refreshed than you are missing the point of angular which is to have back/forward buttons working without full page refresh which makes things faster,

Comment: but I need to reload my page based on the urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `reloadOnSearch` to true? If that doesn't suite your needs, perhaps check out this question: [Force AngularJS to reload a route although option reloadOnSearch is set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137504/force-angularjs-to-reload-a-route-although-option-reloadonsearch-is-set-to-false)

A simpler alternative may be to just force the reload with window.location = newUrl whenever necessary.

Comment: for sure I want to use the ui router states. but still want to use the browser history as well, since the user might click them in the browser.

Comment: You can't have both as far as I know, since the state is erased when the page is reloaded.  You would have to store the state in the url or in a cookie to preserve it through page-reloads.  There are 3rd-party components to help with this.

Comment: @user23878 I updated my answer; I think I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: This is close to the answer. I tried $route.reload(), but it does not work. Then I have to use window.location = newUrl to force to reload.